# Python:How to Send an email Template

Tags: python, smtp

```
import smtplib
fromaddr="satyenarayena.iton@gmail.com"
toaddr="satyenarayena@gmail.com"
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("imp", "testing file")
password="Satyenarayena@8"
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,message)
print "Success"
server.quit()
```

I need Receiver email in the inbox of "to address"

Answer (score 0):

Format the message using this instead:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\nTo: {}\n\n{}'.format("imp", toaddr, "testing file")
```

You may also want to have a "From" field:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\nTo: {}\nFrom: {}\n\n{}'.format("imp", toaddr, fromaddr, "testing file")
```